# Resolving by type name (or id, IComponentRegistration...) in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have **multiple** (generic) types registered with Autofac, all "implementing" a (generic) marker interface. Basically this is the registration and I can't change it (to be e.g. named):

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyType1<>)).As(typeof(IMarkerInterface<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyType2<>)).As(typeof(IMarkerInterface<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyType3<>)).As(typeof(IMarkerInterface<>));
```

where builder is a ContainerBuilder instance.
**Is there a proper way of resolving a type registered as IMarkerInterface<> if I only know the implementation's (type) name (e.g. MyAssembly.MyType2)?**
The registration can simply be selected from IComponentContext.ComponentRegistry.Registrations with a LINQ-query, so in the end I also have the registration object, just can't activate it:

- registration.Activator.ActivateInstance() needs the constructor parameters, but I don't know these (although they can be injected by Autofac if resolved)
- There [used to be a method](http://api.autofac.org/html/F19CFF59.htm) fully suitable for me (as I have the registration id and the ICompontentContext instance), but it seems that now (v2.5.2.830) it's gone.
- As the Service type of the type is the marker interface, I can't resolve by service type as it would resolve the one implementation that happens to be on the top.

A workaround would be I think to mark the types with an interface derived from IMarkerInterface<>, so they would all have unique services too. Another one would be to resolve IEnumerable>, but this would resolve all the implementations, not just the one that's needed (although this has a negligible impact on performance, it's still superfluous). But I don't know if this is the best solution, I feel there should be a more straightforward way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Solution**

Because I can't answer yet, here:
Just mimicking the implementation Autofac.ResolutionExtensions once had, this code works (and I frankly don't know why: constructor params get properly filled; this should mean I've misunderstood what the "parameters" argument is).

```
registration.Activator.ActivateInstance(_componentContext, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());
```

where registration is the IComponentRegistration instance, corresponding to the implementation I wanted to instantiate.
Apparently this also needs something to "initialize" the container with the current type params. A call to

```
_componentContext.IsRegistered<IMarkerInterface<TypeParameter>>()
```

is enough.

Thanks for Sebastien Weber and kvalcanti for the inputs!

Comment: You registered an open generic and now you want to do ... what exactly? AutoFac will close the type definition for you (i.e. if an _IMarkerInterfac<Foo>_ is requested it will serve you an instance of _MyType<Foo>_. What's the problem with that behavior?

Comment: I have clarified the question; sorry it was not clear that there are multiple implementations (implementing the same marker interface) and I'd like to choose one to resolve (in runtime).

Comment: I'm not an expert on AutoFac but in my understanding the above will never work. You register multiple open generic types for the same (equally open) generic target interface. Other containers will only use the last registration (MyType3<>) when they are asked for an instance of (any closed) type IMarkerInterface<SomeType>. I think AutoFac will do something similar.

Comment: It seems Autofac is much smarter than that, see the solution :-).

Comment: IComponentContext.ResolveComponent() is the method that replaces the one you mention IIRC. However there seems to be some info still missing from your question- when do you close the generic types? I.e. specify the Foo in IMarkerInterface<IFoo>?

Comment: Thanks, and that would work equally well. Type params are added in the IsRegistered() call, I just happened to forget it from here. I edited the solution.

Comment: Calling the activator directly as you're doing will bypass circularity checks and some event processing- better to use the resolve method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a per implementation activation, I think you need to register one by one as well.

Comment: The method I linked did basically what I'd like, so there could be some other way... I'll take a look at its implementation.